# Javascript calculation on the fly

Tags: javascript, calculation

I'm a total beginner with JS and trying to learn by my self. I'm hoping I don't get bashed here but Stackoverflow looks like still place to ask questions.

I have this code for calculation and it works. But I want to change prompt to input and show the results on other inputs with a submit button.

Or! What would be amazing if the calculation happens on the fly while user types the numbers (I'm not even sure if that's possible.)

Thanks in advance and this my JS code so far:

```
var incomePerYear = prompt("Income per year: ");

var perYear = parseFloat(((incomePerYear) * 1 / 100) - (incomePerYear * 6 / 1000));

var perMonth = parseFloat(perYear / 12);

document.write("Income per year: " + perYear.toLocaleString('se') + "<br>");

document.write("Income per month: " + perMonth.toFixed(4));
```

Comment: What is it that you need help with? Have you made any attempt using HTML input elements and buttons, binding events on them and finally showing the result?

Comment: Probably it won't work with prompt. But if you will use typical input you can access to "on-change" event https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: @PrzemysławKaczmarczyk Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the event `onkeyup` for on the fly calculation.

BTW, `parseFloat` for a number is superfluous.

```js
function calculate(incomePerYear) {
    var perYear = incomePerYear / 100 - incomePerYear * 6 / 1000,
        perMonth = perYear / 12;

    document.getElementById('year').innerHTML = perYear.toLocaleString('se');
    document.getElementById('month').innerHTML = perMonth.toFixed(4);
}
```

```html
<p>Income per year: <input onkeyup="calculate(this.value)" type="text"></p>
<p>Income per year: <span id="year"></span></p>
<p>Income per month: <span id="month"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this code is super lean. Seeing it this way clears everything up in my mind. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. May be you need to validate the input to make sure its a number.

```
<input type="text" id="incomeperyear">
<div id="perYear"></div>
<div id="perMonth"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

             $('#incomeperyear').on('focus keyup change', function(){
              var incomePerYear = $(this).val();
              var perYear = parseFloat(((incomePerYear) * 1 / 100) - (incomePerYear * 6 / 1000));
              var perMonth = parseFloat(perYear / 12);
              $("#perYear").text('perYear :'+' '+perYear.toLocaleString('se'));
              $("#perMonth").text('perMonth :'+' '+perMonth.toFixed(4));

        });
        })
</script>
```

This will work even you copy the number somewhere else.

https://jsfiddle.net/c982myft/

Comment: Thank you very much but I couldn't get this to work.

Comment: Please check this fiddle. its working fine i guess https://jsfiddle.net/c982myft/

Comment: Yes! Weird that it didn't work here. Cleared the cache and now it works. Thanks again.